# AVAudioPlayer's property give "Cannot assign result of this property"

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, swift

I'm trying to set following property of AVAudioPlayer, but it gives an error.

#### Error:

> Cannot assign result of this property

#### Code:

```
self.player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)
self.player?.numberOfLoops = 0 // Error here
self.player?.delegate = self // Error here
if(!self.player?.prepareToPlay()){... } // This seems to good.
```

Fully confused? Is there any workaround behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optional chaining does not support the setting of property values. It is only used for *querying* (see: getting) properties, and calling methods.

Your code should instead read:

```
if let myPlayer = self.player? {
    myPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0
    myPlayer.delegate = self
}
```

This will only set the properties on the object if it has a value. Since your ivar is most likely defined as `var player: AVAudioPlayer?`, the compiler doesn't actually know whether it will have a value.

As mentioned in the language guide, under the [Calling Properties Through Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/OptionalChaining.html) section:

> > You cannot, however, set a property’s value through optional chaining.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is declare the type of my class's `player` property as `AVAudioPlayer!`. I can do this because I happen to know that this class will always have an audio player. This means, in turn, that I don't have to use `?` or `!` ever again; I can just say `self.player` and everything just works.

If you use this approach and you are ever in doubt about whether you really have a player, simply say `if self.player` - it will be false if no player is there, and now you can avoid  talking to `self.player` as if it were an actual AVAudioPlayer (which would crash your app).

Comment: This approach is also excellent for variables that are set through nib loading (`@IBOutlet`), by the way.

Comment: In fact when you say `@IBOutlet` you get this approach for free;  `@IBOutlet` effectively _means_ (among other things) `weak var myVar : Type! = nil`